# Is there a way to change the current PyGTK theme on Windows?

Tags: python, themes, pygtk

I've written a Python app that uses PyGTK. It runs fine on Linux and looks great. It also runs fine on Windows, but it looks absolutely awful. The default GTK theme looks absolutely nothing like the native Windows GUI elements.

Is there anything I can do to make my Python app look a little better? Perhaps some function I can call to change to theme to something a little nicer?

---

**Edit:** using the `rc_parse()` function suggested in the answer below, I now have:

```
import pygtk,gtk

gtk.rc_parse("C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\GTK\\2.0\\share\\themes\\Bluecurve\\gtk-2.0\\gtkrc")

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
button = gtk.Button()
button.set_label("Hello")

window.add(button)

button.show()
window.show()

gtk.main()
```

...but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the [`rc_parse`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkrcstyle.html#function-gtk--rc-parse) function, which will let you load a gtkrc file with a theme. Also, see http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq21.012.htp&req=show, which shows how to change the GTK theme on windows. Now the problem becomes finding a GTK theme that fits your needs. Some googling turns up http://gtk-wimp.sourceforge.net/, which may be what you need.

Comment: I have my themes in `'C:\Program Files\Common Files\GTK\2.0\share\themes'`, so I would do `gtk.rc_parse("C:\Program Files\Common Files\GTK\2.0\share\themes\MS-Windows\gtk-2.0\gtkrc")`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Although you may not want to hard-code the path.

Comment: @George: if you're running Vista/7, from what I've heard online, there isn't a native theme. Also, try setting the theme globally as per the second link.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [gtk-wimp](http://gtk-wimp.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the matching theme engine in Windows or use a gtk-wimp theme which is on Windows by default.  Bluecurve requires the bluecurve engine.  See http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq21.012.htp&req=show

Answer (score 1):

Try this after the reparse, to change the style:

```
gtk.rc_reset_styles(gtk.settings_get_for_screen(self.window.get_screen()))
```