# GTK Application has old Windows 2000 Skin/Look

Tags: python, gtk, exe

**When I compile my PyGTK script into an .exe, the GUI has the old Windows 2000 look and buttons instead of the Windows XP and up look**

Note this only happens when I convert my script into a .exe. If I run the script(not converted to an .exe) then the widget skins have the normal/modern windows look. But if I convert my script into an .exe using either Py2Exe or PyInstaller they both produce an .exe that uses the old Windows 2000 buttons.

**Do you know how I can retain the Modern Windows Theme/Skin?**

Background Information:

- I am compiling my script using PyInstaller on my Windows 7(64 bit) Laptop
- The python script uses PyGTK 2.0 and Python 2.7

Comment: possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768265/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-current-pygtk-theme-on-windows